# SQL Select MAX and 2nd MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running a query against **MS SQL Server 2008** and am selecting an accountnumber and the max of the column mydate grouped by accountnumber:

```
select AccountNumber,
       max(mydate),
from #SampleData
group by AccountNumber
```

I want to add a column to the result that contains the second highest mydate that is associated with the AccountNumber group. I know it would have to be something like:

```
select max(mydate)
from #SampleData
where mydate < (select max(mydate) from #SampleData)
```

But how do I get both the max and 2nd max in one select query?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Added the RDBMS to the question, MSSQL 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should select the second highest:

```
select AccountNumber,
   max(mydate),
   (select max(SD2.mydate) from #SampleData SD2 where SD2.AccountNumber=#SampleData.AccountNumber AND SD2.mydate<max(#SampleData.mydate))
from #SampleData
group by AccountNumber
```

Comment: Can I get an upvote and selected as the answer then? :-)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify your DBMS so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select accountnumber,
       rn,
       mydate
from (
   select accountnumber, 
          mydate, 
          row_number() over (partition by accountnumber order by mydate desc) as rn
   from #SampleData
) t
where rn <= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select AccountNumber,
MAX(Case when Rnum = 1 Then mydate END) mydate_1,
MAX(Case when Rnum = 2 Then mydate END) mydate_2
From
(
select 
AccountNumber, mydate,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By AccountNumber ORDER BY mydate DESC) as Rnum
from #SampleData
) V
Group By AccountNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a TOP N clause combined with an order by:

```
select    
          TOP 2
          accountnumber, 
          mydate, 
          row_number() over (partition by accountnumber order by mydate desc) as rn
from #SampleData
ORDER BY
          row_number() over (partition by accountnumber order by mydate desc)
```