# Need help tweaking a query for a specific output

Tags: sql-server

I have code to help me manage software usage in our server environment based on parsed logs stored as tables in SQL Server. Right now the code gets me a monthly report on the count of each product by Country. There are a lot of products, but my reporting requirement is for the second highest peak of license counts. So I am wanting to see if this query can be tweaked to just report the Country, Product and second highest count?

```
Select Country, Product, UsageDate, ReportMonth, COUNT (User) as LicenseCount 
from 
(
SELECT  DISTINCT([dbo].[EsriLMReport].[User]), [dbo].[EsriLMReport].Product, [dbo].[EsriLMReport].UsageDate,[dbo].[EsriLMReport].ReportMonth,[dbo].[vw_WorkdayCountriesCalc].Country
FROM         [dbo].[EsriLMReport] INNER JOIN
                         [dbo].[vw_WorkdayCountriesCalc] ON [dbo].[EsriLMReport].[User] = [dbo].[vw_WorkdayCountriesCalc].UserName
                         ) as t1
Group by Country, Product,UsageDate, ReportMonth
order by Country Asc, UsageDate asc
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942235/sql-select-max-and-2nd-max

Comment: I am not sure I follow what that post is saying. I will read on the MAX keyword to see if I understand it. One past had something about the top 2, but I would need to figure out where to put either of these in my query.

Comment: I reread all of that thread, the issue is because my first select is setting up the License Count in a temp table t1, I don't see how I can get the max or 2nd max from the query.

Comment: I took my original query and created a temp table, but then tried this code: ```select Country, Product, max(LicenseCount) as LicenseCount
from dbo.EsriDesktopCounttemp
where LicenseCount < (Select max(licensecount) from dbo.EsriDesktopCounttemp)
Group By Country, Product, LicenseCount``` But it didn't work.